# Local fonts not loading in a Polymer, Chrome App

Tags: css, fonts, polymer, google-chrome-app

I'm attempting to use a local font for my Polymer Chrome App. I'm trying to use @font-face in CSS. Here's what I got:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'robotolight';
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.svg#robotolight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}




@font-face {
    font-family: 'robotolight_italic';
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-lightitalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-lightitalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-lightitalic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-lightitalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-lightitalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-lightitalic-webfont.svg#robotolight_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I use this font-face on an h1 here:

```
#CaseFiles-h1{   
    font-family: 'robotolight';
    //font-weight: normal;        <- no luck
    //font-style: normal;         <- no luck
}
```

Unfortunately, the font isn't loaded and I get some default serif font instead.

Any ideas?

I was hoping to keep the font local instead of using Google fonts or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declate your `@font-face` outside of your Polymer object. Then you can use it in the polymer template.

```
<style media="screen">
    font-family: 'robotolight';
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../assets/fonts/roboto-light-webfont.svg#robotolight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
</style>
<dom-module id="polymer-element>
    <template>
        <span style="font-familiy: robotolight">Hello</span>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

A blog post about that is [here](http://robdodson.me/at-font-face-doesnt-work-in-shadow-dom/).

Answer (score 0):

Look on Polymer's font-roboto [linked definition](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&lang=en). There are *font-size* defined in absolute measures like 100, 200, etc. Defining *font-size: normal;* is too rude. Some components may request absolutely or relatively measured *font-size*. So, try to define all corresponding font-sizes to match all possible requests, even if you won't include all font types (thin, light, medium, etc).

Also, I think you should fix robotolight_italic definition:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'robotolight';
  /* ... */
  font-style: italic;
}
```